# fixed div on top displaying layer problem

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a div fixed on the top but looks like the layer overlaps.

CSS:

```
    #fsancy {
        background-color:#ddd;
        position: fixed;
        display: block;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        left: 50%;
        top: 0%;
        margin-left: -100px; /*half the width*/
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="fsancy">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center fluid fixme" id=""
         style="background-color: #ff0033; max-width: 100%; color: #ffffff; font-size: xx-large">Share £200 With A
        Friend
    </div>
</div>
```

Picture example
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed position elements are not part of the regular document flow, so in your particular case you have to add some `margin-top` to the first regular element which is high enough to avoid the overlap / fit under the fixed header.

Answer (score 0):

@Michelbach Alin, use position absolute and z-index properties for fix as a layer.

```
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Reference.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp